# Add an option to hide the question for editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, asking-questions, definition-phase

Recently I asked a question, only to realized that the image that I posted should be cropped. Because it takes few minutes to do, I deleted a question and expected it to stay for some time (like deleted answer stays). But I was wrong - the question was gone.

Would it be a good idea add a button to temporary hide a question? (for example within the first 15 minutes after the question is posted, to hide it for 15 minutes, after which the question shows)

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't have answers with at least one upvote, you can already do that by deleting, editing, and undeleting your question.

Just make sure you keep the page open - once you delete it, it's no longer in your questions list.

Comment: Or keep the url handy.

Comment: well... that is the thing. Once you refresh the page, or click anything, the question is gone

Comment: @VJo really? You don't see your own deleted questions? Weird, I thought you can always  see your own (but I don't know, due to reputation points I see them all) - in that case, this won't work, sorry

Comment: You need 10k for that. Anything below and the question is gone

Comment: This is bad! (comment-too-short-to-post)

Comment: @Dani what is bad - what is said in the comment above, or in the answer?

Comment: The system - not your answer. That's just factual.

Comment: @Dani you mean that you're not shown your own deleted question from a minute ago? Yeah, I agree.